# How to access encrypted device on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mount, encryption

Before Ubuntu upgrade to 16.04, I used to access a encrypted drive this way:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen -d /home/supervisor/lacie.key /dev/disk/by-uuid/8cff279a-aaca-425a-91ab-16097d81f7a4 lacie
sudo mount /dev/mapper/lacie /mnt/lacie
```

After upgrade to 16.04, the first command does not work anymore.

```
Failed to setup dm-crypt key mapping for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/8cff279a-aaca-425a-91ab-16097d81f7a4.
Check that kernel supports aes-cbc-plain cipher (check syslog for more info).
```

How can I fix this?

I tried the following but it didn't work either:

[How to mount an old encrypted disk on Ubuntu? - SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/563081/how-to-mount-an-old-encrypted-disk-on-ubuntu)

Result of the `dmesg | tail`

```
[ 1344.837925] usb 2-1.6: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 1344.992496] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=059f, idProduct=106b
[ 1344.992501] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 1344.992504] usb 2-1.6: Product: Rugged Mini USB 3.0
[ 1344.992506] usb 2-1.6: Manufacturer: LaCie
[ 1344.992509] usb 2-1.6: SerialNumber: 0000000075c6da0500e4
[ 1345.060718] usb-storage 2-1.6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1345.060873] scsi6 : usb-storage 2-1.6:1.0
[ 1345.060949] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 1346.059668] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     LaCie    Rugged Mini USB3 1053 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 1346.060123] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[ 1346.063786] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Spinning up disk...
[ 1347.067710] ..ready
[ 1348.079903] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[ 1348.081024] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[ 1348.081030] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 1348.082106] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 1348.133176]  sdd: sdd1
[ 1348.136384] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: Does it give you any output? (First one which does not works).

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I forgot to add the command output.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo dmesg | tail -n 50` after you try to open the LUKS device? Also, `aes-cbc-plain` cipher mode is deprecated since quite a while.

Comment: As this SSD will be used on older Ubuntu systems, I imagine I have to stick with this cipher mode. But I'm open to use other cipher modes if older ubuntu versions can read the drive. I will post the dmesg on question in a moment.

Comment: Please edit the dmesg output to include the *last 50 lines*. Specifically, run `dmesg | tail -n 50` *after* trying to open the LUKS device.